# GTK# TreeViewColumn with multiple renderers

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am working at chat with stickers on Mono C# with GTK# GUI. While googling i have founded that best widget for this purpose is TextView. Problem in creating ListStore for column with multiple renderers:

```
    TreeView messageLog=new TreeView();
    #Creating a column
    TreeViewColumn messageColumn = new TreeViewColumn();
    messageLog.AppendColumn(messageColumn);
    #Creating model for tree
    ListStore messageStore = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(Gdk.Pixbuf));
    messageLog.Model = messageStore;
    #Packing 2 renderers into column
    CellRendererText textCell = new CellRendererText();
    messageColumn.PackEnd(textCell, true);
    messageColumn.AddAttribute(textCell, "text", 0);
    CellRendererPixbuf stickerCell = new CellRendererPixbuf();
    messageColumn.PackStart(stickerCell, false);
    messageColumn.AddAttribute(stickerCell, "pixbuf", 1);
```

Add text to TreeView:

```
    messageStore.AppendValues(value);
```

This way, i can add pictures to TreeView only with:

```
    messageStore.AppendValues(null, new Gdk.Pixbug("red.png");
```

But it shows like in new column. Is there a better way to define ListStore or append values so picture will be shown in same column as message? Or maybe there is a better widget for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do yo want a single column for text in which pictures can appear everywhere, or do you want a first column with a picture representing the author of the message, and the message itself in the next column?

Comment: You cannot have, AFAIK, two cell renderers in the same column. Have you checked out this? https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/treeview-tutorial/

Comment: @Baltasarq I need a single column, where picture can appear instead of text in same as text place. Yes, i checked this, citing: "For example you can pack an image and text into the same column, which often makes much more sense than creating a separate column for each." but it does not saying how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right, I've been able to do it (more than one item in a single column), following (or inferring from) the [Mono's Gtk# tree view tutorial](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/treeview-tutorial/).

```
namespace TreeViewMultipleRenderers
{
    public class MainWindowView: Gtk.Window
    {
        public MainWindowView()
            : base( Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel )
        {
            this.SetGeometryHints( this,
                                  new Gdk.Geometry { MinHeight = 400, MinWidth = 600 },
                                  Gdk.WindowHints.MinSize );

            this.Build();
        }

        void BuildIcons()
        {
            this.IconYes = new Gdk.Pixbuf(
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(),
                "TreeViewMultipleRenderers.Res.yes.png", 16, 16 );

            this.IconNo = new Gdk.Pixbuf(
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(),
                "TreeViewMultipleRenderers.Res.no.png", 16, 16 );
        }

        Gtk.TreeView BuildTreeView()
        {
            var toret = new Gtk.TreeView();

            // Index column
            var columnIndex = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn {
                Title = "#"
            };

            var indexRenderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
            columnIndex.PackStart( indexRenderer, expand: true );
            columnIndex.AddAttribute( indexRenderer, "text", 0 );

            // Data column
            var columnData = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn {
                Title = "Mixed column"
            };

            var dataRenderer1 = new Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf();
            columnData.PackStart( dataRenderer1, expand: false );
            columnData.AddAttribute( dataRenderer1, "pixbuf", 1 );

            var dataRenderer2 = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
            columnData.PackStart( dataRenderer2, expand: true );
            columnData.AddAttribute( dataRenderer2, "text", 2 );

            toret.AppendColumn( columnIndex );
            toret.AppendColumn( columnData );

            // Model
            var store = new Gtk.ListStore( typeof( string ), typeof( Gdk.Pixbuf ), typeof( string ) );
            toret.Model = store;

            store.AppendValues( "1", this.IconYes, "works" );
            store.AppendValues( "2", this.IconNo, "does not work" );

            return toret;
        }

        void Build()
        {
            this.BuildIcons();

            this.TreeView = this.BuildTreeView();

            this.Add( this.TreeView );
        }

        public Gtk.TreeView TreeView {
            get; set;
        }

        public Gdk.Pixbuf IconYes {
            get; private set;
        }

        public Gdk.Pixbuf IconNo {
            get; private set;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see any important difference with the relevant parts of the code you posted, so I guess the problem must be elsewhere. You can find this code in the [GtkTreeViewMultipleRenderers Github repository](https://github.com/Baltasarq/GtkCsTreeViewMultipleRenderers). I've also uploaded an executable in the [releases section of the repository](https://github.com/Baltasarq/GtkCsTreeViewMultipleRenderers/releases).

Hope this helps.